# how can I start mapred for Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop

I set up a Hadoop test environment on three virtual CentOS 6.2. All things go smoothly but start-mapred .

what I always get is:
2012-02-03 19:54:17,592 WARN org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker: Failed to initialize recovery manager. 
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: java.io.IOException: File /home/hadoop/devx/var/tmp/mapred/system/jobtracker.info could o
nly be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1

and I have checked nameSpaceID on name node and data node, they are identical.

is there anything I am doing wrong?

Comment: Resolved! I forgot close iptable on data node. FML

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop is so sensitive to host names and IPs